# Where is Power Bi being hosted?

Tags: powerbi

Where is PowerBI being hosted. If I make a power BI report and provide a link to the report or dashboard. where is that link being referenced from?

From our Azure DB?

Is it possible to have power bi hosted in a VM? So that the links I provide to the report are directly from and referenced from the VM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI is currently cloud hosted by Microsoft, but it will be integrated into SSRS, so it can be hosted in-house. For details follow the SQL Server Team blog from Microsoft.

The [January Blog Post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/01/17/power-bi-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services-january-2017-technical-preview-now-available/) announces the technical preview for download.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on your Azure DB comment, Power BI is independent from the data sources.   If you were to host Power BI in-house you would have to set your Azure DB firewall to allow access from that server.    Alternatively you might also migrate the database in-house as well.